# Problem copying range from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet to a new worksheet. The code below works fine until the last line, at which point it throws a "Application-defined or object-defined error".

It looks like I am doing the same thing for the new worksheet range as I did for the existing wks/rng; don't understand why [rngSolution] is not ?instantiated?

This code is in a workbook module. I'm using Office/Excel 365 on this. I'm pretty familiar with VBA in the Access object model, but not so much in the Excel obj model.

Thanks for your help.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next

'-- delete the Solution wks if it exists
Worksheets("Solution").Delete

On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'-- (re)create the Solutions wks
Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Solution"

'-- copy original data to new worksheet/range
Dim rngDataset As Range, rngSolution As Range

Set rngDataset = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataSet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Debug.Print rngDataset.Name; " "; rngDataset.Rows.Count; " "; rngDataset.Columns.Count

Set rngSolution = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Solution").Range("A1")
rngDataset.Copy Destination:=rngSolution

Debug.Print rngSolution.Name; " "; rngSolution.Rows.Count; " "; rngSolution.Columns.Count
```

Comment: The code works fine as soon as I change `rngDataset.Name` against `rngDataset.address` and `rngSolution.Name` against `rngSolution.address` in the two debug.print lines.

Answer (score 0):

`rngDataset` and `rngSolution` are not Named ranges and, as a result, the range property **Name** is not available. You can set the names, if you wish to do so as, for example, in

```
rngDataset.Name = "Dataset"
```

although it is not clear why you would want to.

Comment: ok, I see it, now. I was just trying to verify that I had created a range.
But why does "Debug.Print rngDataset.Name; ..."  work? It's not a Named range, either.
Oh, well, Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mark;  It is a mystery to me why `Debug.Print rngDataset.Name;` works for you--it should not... (what does it print out?) Did you presented above all of your code or not? Is it possible you actually named a range, unwittingly, sometime earlier? Please check this by running `?ThisWorkbook.Names.Count` in the immediate window: it should be 0.